# Error while crawling after an arbitrary amount of time

Tags: elasticsearch, stormcrawler

So I have two classes responsible for Seeding (Injecting Urls) and crawling.

ESSeedInjector Class:

```
public class ESSeedInjector extends ConfigurableTopology {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
    ConfigurableTopology.start(new ESSeedInjector(), new String[]{".","seeds.txt","-local","-conf", "es-conf.yaml","--sleep","5000"});
}

@Override
public int run(String[] args) {

    if (args.length == 0) {
        System.err.println("ESSeedInjector seed_dir file_filter");
        return -1;
    }

    conf.setDebug(true);

    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    Scheme scheme = new StringTabScheme(Status.DISCOVERED);

    builder.setSpout("spout", new FileSpout(args[0], args[1], scheme));

    Fields key = new Fields("url");

    builder.setBolt("filter", new URLFilterBolt()).fieldsGrouping("spout",
            key);

    builder.setBolt("enqueue", new StatusUpdaterBolt(), 10)
            .customGrouping("filter", new URLStreamGrouping());

    return submit("ESSeedInjector", conf, builder);
}
```

Crawler Class:

```
public class ESCrawlTopology extends ConfigurableTopology {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurableTopology.start(new ESCrawlTopology(), new String[]{"-conf", "es-conf.yaml", "-local"});
}

@Override
protected int run(String[] args) {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    int numWorkers = ConfUtils.getInt(getConf(), "topology.workers", 1);

    int numShards = 1;

    builder.setSpout("spout", new CollapsingSpout(), numShards);

    builder.setBolt("status_metrics", new StatusMetricsBolt())
            .shuffleGrouping("spout");

    builder.setBolt("partitioner", new URLPartitionerBolt(), numWorkers)
            .shuffleGrouping("spout");

    builder.setBolt("fetch", new FetcherBolt(), numWorkers).fieldsGrouping(
            "partitioner", new Fields("key"));

    builder.setBolt("sitemap", new SiteMapParserBolt(), numWorkers)
            .localOrShuffleGrouping("fetch");

    builder.setBolt("parse", new JSoupParserBolt(), numWorkers)
            .localOrShuffleGrouping("sitemap");

    builder.setBolt("indexer", new IndexerBolt(), numWorkers)
            .localOrShuffleGrouping("parse");

    Fields furl = new Fields("url");

    builder.setBolt("status", new StatusUpdaterBolt(), numWorkers)
            .fieldsGrouping("fetch", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
            .fieldsGrouping("sitemap", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
            .fieldsGrouping("parse", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl)
            .fieldsGrouping("indexer", Constants.StatusStreamName, furl);

    builder.setBolt("deleter", new DeletionBolt(), numWorkers)
            .localOrShuffleGrouping("status",
                    Constants.DELETION_STREAM_NAME);

    conf.registerMetricsConsumer(MetricsConsumer.class);
    conf.registerMetricsConsumer(LoggingMetricsConsumer.class);

    return submit("crawl", conf, builder);
}
}
```

The flow goes -

Run ESSeedInjector class (This successfully injects urls).

Run Crawler class.

Now this start crawling but at an arbitrary time it will produce an error.

```
18892 [elasticsearch[_client_][listener][T#2]] ERROR c.d.s.e.p.CollapsingSpout -  Exception with ES query
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [2rbuRko][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/search]
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [2rbuRko][127.0.0.1:9300][indices:data/read/msearch]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Validation Failed: 1: no requests added;
    at org.elasticsearch.action.ValidateActions.addValidationError(ValidateActions.java:29) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.MultiSearchRequest.validate(MultiSearchRequest.java:90) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.TransportAction.execute(TransportAction.java:131) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:64) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.support.HandledTransportAction$TransportHandler.messageReceived(HandledTransportAction.java:54) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.RequestHandlerRegistry.processMessageReceived(RequestHandlerRegistry.java:69) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendLocalRequest(TransportService.java:621) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.access$000(TransportService.java:73) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService$3.sendRequest(TransportService.java:133) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequestInternal(TransportService.java:569) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendRequest(TransportService.java:502) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendChildRequest(TransportService.java:529) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.sendChildRequest(TransportService.java:520) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.SearchTransportService.sendExecuteMultiSearch(SearchTransportService.java:182) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.ExpandSearchPhase.run(ExpandSearchPhase.java:93) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executePhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:144) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.AbstractSearchAsyncAction.executeNextPhase(AbstractSearchAsyncAction.java:138) ~[elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase.moveToNextPhase(FetchSearchPhase.java:207) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase.lambda$innerRun$2(FetchSearchPhase.java:105) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase.innerRun(FetchSearchPhase.java:117) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase.access$000(FetchSearchPhase.java:45) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.action.search.FetchSearchPhase$1.doRun(FetchSearchPhase.java:87) ~[?:?]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingAbstractRunnable.doRun(ThreadContext.java:638) [elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.AbstractRunnable.run(AbstractRunnable.java:37) [elasticsearch-5.3.0.jar:5.3.0]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_151]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_151]
```

Not sure what is causing the error but patterns I have seen is that if a wipe the data from ElasticSearch by running ESIndex.Init and then execute ESSeedInjector then the ESCrawlTopology class, it will produce an exception very early on in the crawling process (After parsing the seed url).

However if I run ESCrawlTopology again, (without doing anything else), it will produce the exception but at a much later time.

EDIT: When I change from CollapsingSpout() to AggregationSpout() I now get this log.

```
15409 [elasticsearch[_client_][listener][T#1]] INFO  c.d.s.e.p.AggregationSpout -  ES query returned 0 hits from 0 buckets in 2 msec with 0 already being processed
```

Nothing gets processed or indexed anymore in ES.

Comment: Not sure what's happening here, that's not something I've seen so far. Since you are using an older version of  ES, I can't necessarily reproduce the problem with the current code. Are you running the injector at the same time as the crawl topology? The injection topo is usually done in local mode and for a short period. Having said that it should not matter whether you have them running at the same time or not. it would be interesting to work out why you are not getting anything with the aggregationspout.

Comment: Any ideas? I have modified the config so error is not produced but after a certain amount of hits (400~) i would get the 'ES query returned 0 hits...' message. This will keep getting printed out until I stop the application. Restarting the application will also print the message too.